# Unable to find permissions in the Required Permissions dropdown in Android Manifest Section of my app properties

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, android-manifest

I am working on a new app in Xamarin.Forms using Visual Studio 2017. This is a test app and I am following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/get-started/hello-xamarin-forms/quickstart?tabs=vswin) tutorial. I have completed the common code for the application. However, during implementing the platform-specific phone dialer code as a DependencyService, I am unable to find required permissions in the dropdown (Required Permissions dropdown) under myApp.Android project in the solution explorer.

Is there any way to locate the required permission in the dropdown or I am missing some components while setting up the environment. Please look at this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7w1g.png) I have taken.

Comment: if it is not available then just copy the text and paste it in your manifest file with the required changes and it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @G.hakim has said, your can add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

into your manifest file directly.

Please refer to [this](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/5ff7ad3499ea8c7842543414ec96e8055085a7d8/Phoneword/VS2017/Phoneword/Phoneword.Android/Properties/AndroidManifest.xml).

Answer (score 0):

Although @G.hakim and @Joe have both shared their opinions about my problem but as I didn't included some of the optional components of Xamarin during installing (in my case, modifying VS 2017) permissions were not visible in the dropdown. As soon I included Xamarin Workbooks, Xamarin Profiler and Xamarin Remoted Simulator components from the optional category of Mobile Development with .Net during modifying VS 2017, I was able to locate the permissions in the dropdown.